# Handling Exception is ASP.NET Webforms using Custom validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Im having a problem handing an exception in ASP.net WebForms(i'm a beginner)
i want to display the error in the webform using CustomValidator but with no luck, below is my code.

```
 protected void dvEmployeeList_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            GridViewRow rowSelect = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
            int rowindex = rowSelect.RowIndex;

            string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];

            if (confirmValue == "Yes")
            {
                try
                {

                    int empID;

                    empID = int.TryParse(dvEmployeeList.DataKeys[rowindex].Value.ToString(), out empID) ? empID : 0;
                    oEmployeeBLL.DeleteEmployee(empID);
                    dvEmployeeList.DataSource = oEmployeeBLL.GetEmployeeList();
                    dvEmployeeList.DataBind();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var delConstrainsVal = new CustomValidator();
                    delConstrainsVal.IsValid = false;
                    delConstrainsVal.ErrorMessage = "Update failed: " + ex.Message;
                    delConstrainsVal.Text = delConstrainsVal.ErrorMessage;
                    Page.Validators.Add(delConstrainsVal);

                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('User cancel!')", true);
            }

        }
```

it catch the exception but didnt display the message on the on the form.

Please guide me, thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Validators are meant to validate user input, not to display server errors. You should consider using a simple `<asp:Label>`.

The reason why the error doesn't appear is probably because validation happens before the control is added.